# The World and The Stranger

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I have been through Act 1 over a dozen times by now but I can not seem to figure out the timing to get these two conversations from Shen.

I assume that The Stranger happens some time after you bring the buy back form the crater (Yes I know whom he is already) but I have no idea what leads up to it specifically.

As for The World, no idea. Order in the list seems to imply it is some time after you take care of the Skeleton King but I have noticed the order in the list is not always chronological (Found this out with the books in Act 3 where one of them is among the last you collect).

If these should be separate questions let me know but I fear a question for every check box on these achievements.. I just can not figure these talking points out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally just loaded up a character to the appropriate quest, and went and talked to him.

**The World**
Available at the start of the Quest: The Broken Blade (Act I)

**The Stranger**
Available at the start of the Quest: The Imprisoned Angel (Act I)

The following website has a list of all the conversations and where you start them:

http://soe.hubpages.com/hub/Covetous-Shen-Lore-and-Character-Dialogue-Guide-Diablo-3

Comment: Awesome find.  That will be very useful for rounding out the conversation achievements.

Answer (score 1):

#### The world

On your first encounter with Maghda's spirit in the Khazra Den in the quest **Sword of the Stranger**, after you grab the sword shard, come back to town and talk to Shen. The dialog option will appear.

#### The Stranger

As soon as you complete **The Cursed Hold** of the chapter **Imprisoned Angel**, return to town and talk to Shen.

Answer (score 0):

"The World" is just after you found the 2nd sword shard. Talk to Shen before talking to The Stranger.

Comment: Consider masking the strange's name for people who might not yet know?

Answer (score 0):

The Stranger:
Talk to Leah upon entering and then talk to Shen.
That is all you need to do; just tested it myself.
Hope that helps.